# In HTML, what lang attribute code should I use for a fantasy or other invented langauge?

Tags: html, lang

I am writing a website that has some content in a made-up language. What `lang=""` code should I use for those sections of text?

Comment: What type of characters does it contains?

Comment: They're Latin characters. Think of it as if I were writing Klingon. How would I mark up that I was writing in Klingon?

Comment: I've updated my answer with details on Klingon. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`edit` I noticed Klingon mentioned in a comment after I posted this answer.

Klingon's [language code](https://iso639-3.sil.org/code/tlh) is `tlh`

---

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang), the `lang` attribute defines:

> the language that non-editable elements are written in, or the language that the editable elements should be written in by the user.

Furthermore:

> The default value of `lang` is `unknown`, therefore it is recommended to always specify this attribute with the appropriate value.

I would suggest that if the website is mostly written in English, you should define the `<html lang="en">`, and then overwrite the parts of the site that are not written in the default differently.

Maybe something like: `<article lang="tlh">`

There are *a lot* of languages – [here is a list](https://r12a.github.io/app-subtags/).

Comment: That updated link for Klingon coincidentally gave my answer! It lists four special codes: “mis” Uncoded languages; “mul” Multiple languages; “und” Undetermined; “zxx” No linguistic content, Not applicable. Thanks! I would upvote you but I don't have quite enough reputation (11 instead of 15, d'oh).

Comment: No worries! Happy to help :)